# Eclipse menu bar won't show - Ubuntu 16.04 - Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu

I recently installed eclipse Mars with the installer.

However, the menu at the top won't show : I can't see File, Edit...

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

[Eclipse.ini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zYsG.png)

[Screenshot of the problem at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38Q6N.png)

Thanks in advance for you help

Comment: Sounds like you're running [Unity](https://unity.ubuntu.com/) (I don't care for it myself).

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem today. I found the answer in Ask Ubuntu. [It](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762137/applications-menu-missing-from-menu-bar) fix my system. I just execute this command on dash:

```
$ initctl restart unity-panel-service
```

Answer (score 3):

It works for me with David M. Karr's suggestion.  To be more specific,

Go to Ubuntu 16.04 All Settings (mechanic gear icon), Click on Appearance...
All Settings"->"Appearance"->"Behavior" and change the "Show the menus for a window" setting:  Check both of the following:
1. In the window's title bar and 2. Always displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You're only showing the Eclipse window.  Apparently, Ubuntu will default to showing the application menu bar in the desktop status bar, instead of the application window.  Go to "Settings"->"Appearance"->"Behavior" and change the "Show the menus for a window" setting.  Even then, you will only see the menu if you hover the mouse there.

Comment: I try it and it doesn't work. I think the problem is in eclipse.

Comment: What exactly did you "try"?  What was "Show the menus for a window" set to?  Also, what is "Menus visibility" set to?

Comment: I did exaclty what you said and the menu won't show. It appear on all the other program that I have. What is strange in eclipse is that when I hit Ctrl + F, I'm on the menu but I dont see it at the top.